# WordPress Plugin: Hook to post_row_actions function the content of a custom PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, wordpress-hook

I created a WordPress Plugin, with a hook to create links below the overview of posts in the backend(for a custom post type).

[image: Action]

The link should redirect to a custom PHP-File. Which is currently solved like this (for Terminierungsverwaltung):

```
class CustomPlugin
{


function __construct(){

    #... more code

    /**
     * Terminverwaltung
     */
    add_filter( 'post_row_actions', array( $this,'termin_add_user_action_button'), 10, 2 );

    #... more code

}

#... more code

function termin_add_user_action_button($actions, $post){
    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = $post->ID;                       //post ID
    $poll_id;                                   //poll ID

    
    $wordpress_polls = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wordpress_id, poll_id FROM " . self::WORDPRESS_TABLE_NAME . " WHERE wordpress_id = " . $post_id);
    $wordpress_polls_rows = $wpdb->num_rows;
    
    foreach($wordpress_polls as $wordpress_poll){
        $poll_id  = $wordpress_poll->poll_id;
    }

    if($wordpress_polls_rows === NULL || $wordpress_polls_rows === 0){
        return $actions;
    } else{
        if(get_post_type() === 'workshop'){
            $url = add_query_arg(
                array(
                  'post_id' => $post->ID,
                  'poll_id' => $poll_id,
                ), 
                plugins_url( '/attendees.php', __FILE__ )
              );
            $actions['termin_add_user'] = '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">Teilnehmerverwaltung</a>';
        }
        return $actions;
    }
}

#... more code

}
```

So currently I am pointing directly to the source file `attendees.php` (which is located inside the plugin directory) and it is not protected.

My aim is to protect the `attendees.php` with:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
```

Obviously, I will need to hook the file somehow to the plugin or WordPress, so ABSPATH is defined. But I am not sure how to do it. Does anyone know how to get this done?

I am new to PHP and WordPress, so sorry if this is a newbie question.

Thanks in advance!

THE-E

In case the `attendees.php` is of importance, it has currently this structure, and should be displayed independently:

```
<?php
// if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
//  exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
// }
require '../../../wp-load.php';
require 'src/attendees_function.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href = "style/attendeesStyle.css" />
    <title>Teilnehmerverwaltung: <?php echo get_the_title($_REQUEST['post_id']);?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php add_user_form(); ?>
    <?php delete_attendee(); ?>
    <?php upload(); ?>
    <H1>Teilnehmerverwaltung</H1>
    <H2><?php echo get_the_title($_REQUEST['post_id']);?></H2>
    <section>
    <div id="add-users-upload">
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="csv-form">
        <input type="file" name="teilnehmer-csv" accept=".csv"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="csv-upload" id="top-buttons">Teilnehmer CSV hochladen</button>
      </form>

      <form method="post">
        <label for="kuerzel">Kürzel:</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="poll-id" value="<?php $poll_id = $_REQUEST['poll_id']; echo $poll_id; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?php $table = "oc_polls_share"; echo $table; ?>"/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="input-kuerzel" name="kuerzel"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="add-user-form" id="top-buttons">Teilnehmer anlegen</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </section>
    <div id="table-div">
        <table>
          </thead>
            <tr>
            <td id="index">#</td>
            <td id="index">Status</td>
            <td id="header">Kürzel</td>
            <td id="header">E-Mail</td>
            <td id="header">Vorname</td>
            <td id="header">Nachname</td>
            <td id="header">Geburtstag</td>
            <td id="header">Token</td>
            <td id="header">Löschen</td>
            <td id="header">Umfrage-Link</td>
            <td id="header">Webseiten-Link</td>
            <td id="header">Senden</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php
            
            $nextcloud_base_url = "https://example.com";
            $nextcloud_attendees_base_url = $nextcloud_base_url . "/apps/polls/s/";

            if(isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) && isset($_REQUEST['poll_id'])){
              $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];                  //post ID
              $poll_id = $_REQUEST['poll_id'];                                  //poll ID
            }
            $wordpress_polls_table_name = 'wordpress_polls';    //storage of primary keys of post id and poll id
            $polls_share_table_name = 'oc_polls_share'; //attendees table
            
            $wordpress_polls = get_wordpress_polls($wordpress_polls_table_name, $post_id);
            $wordpress_polls_rows = get_wordpress_polls($wordpress_polls_table_name, $post_id);


            $poll_id = get_poll_id($wordpress_polls);

            if($wordpress_polls_rows === NULL || $wordpress_polls_rows === 0){
              return;
            } else {
              $attendees = get_attendees($polls_share_table_name, $poll_id);
              $attendees_rows = get_attendees_rows($polls_share_table_name, $poll_id);
              create_attendee_rows($attendees, $nextcloud_attendees_base_url); 

            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
    <div id="legende">
      <p>
        Status-Legende:<br>
        &#x274C; = Abstimmung nicht erfolgt<br>
        &#x2705; = Abstimmung erfolgt
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I am looking into the Custom Endpoints Documentation, but couldn't get it to work for now.

Meanwhile a picture of the content I want to integrate (attendees.php)
[image]

Comment: _“The link should redirect to a custom PHP-File.”_ - no, that is exactly what it should _not_ do. Instead, you should set up a proper custom route, that when navigated to triggers the desired function/method. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Thank for your reply. Can you tell me where to implement it in my case? So the aim is, once I click on "Teilnehmerverwaltung"(Link) below the post, it should display the content of attendees.php

Comment: So far I just read, that I will have to add the custom PHP-file to my theme folder and create a page and link it to the new "template". I somehow find this solution "dirty" since it is part of my plugin. Is there a "cleaner" solution?
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-create-a-custom-PHP-page-in-WordPress
Is copying the php to the current theme folder when installing the plugin a solution? Still not "clean" to my understanding...

Comment: Plugins can overwrite the normal template hierarchy. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/create-custom-page-templates-with-plugins

Comment: Is this the best practise to add a custom site with PHP logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to solve this which I'll try to outline. These are *not* in order of recommendation, just stream on consciousness. I would recommend #2, if it is viable, however.

## 1 - Manually boot WordPress

This [question shows](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049/12496) shows how to do this and [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/12496) gives pros and cons for each, but the general idea is to `require_once` either the `wp-load.php` or the `wp-blog-header.php` files from root, and you'd probably want the former. Doing this, however, is usually discouraged and I would only recommend it for cases where you need access to basic WordPress functions. If you do this, WordPress doesn't know what your security requirements are, so it will be up to you to perform access control using things like `current_user_can`.

Although I posted this first, I would strongly recommended avoiding this, and if you are distributing your plugin, especially in the WordPress.org repo, absolutely don't do this because I'm pretty certain it would be rejected.

## 2 - Create a true WordPress admin page

If you are willing so sacrifice some pixel space (for the admin toolbars), this is the recommended way. Just register a menu using [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and you can either `echo` or `include`/`require` your code:

```php
add_action(
    'admin_menu',
    static function () {
        add_menu_page(
            'My Plugin',
            'My Plugin',
            'manage_options',
            'my-plugin',
            static function () {
                // Either echo here or use an include/require
                echo '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
            }
        );
    }
);
```

The URL to this page is based on the fourth parameter to that function, which using the above would be `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin`. Access control is handled automatically with the third parameter which makes certain that the user has the `manage_options` permission. You can customize that as needed, and optionally create your own permissions, too.

## 3 - Inject via templates

The `template_include` function is used to determine which front-end WordPress template to use. Personally, I don't like using this for admin stuff because I like to keep things separate from each other, but that's just me. In this code sample below I'm setting a template in the theme's folder, but it could just as easily be in the plugin's folder.

```php
add_filter(
    'template_include',
    static function ($template) {
        // Pick whatever logic you want here, it could be `_GET` or `_POST` or pretty much anything
        if ('my-plugin' === ($_GET['action'] ?? null)) {
            $template = get_template_directory() . '/searchform.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
);
```

The `if` logic is where you do whatever you want. I'm just showing a simple `_GET` check where the URL would be `/?action=my-plugin`. Security, once again, is up to you, but you have full access to WordPress core functions like `current_user_can` to do whatever is necessary.

## 4 - Rewrite endpoints

This is actually a version of #3 because you are just making the URL prettier. I personally think it is over-complicated because it is a multi-step process with a lot of moving parts, but if the URL is important to you it might work. Make sure to flush your permalinks! The key to this is [`rewrite_rules_array`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rewrite_rules_array/) where you register a custom regex for the URL and you can provide whatever logic you need, including querystrings and whatever.

```php
// Register a global variable for the URL so that WordPress is aware that you care about it
add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    static function ($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'my-plugin';
        return $vars;
    }
);

// Add special regex-like syntax for URLs. You can go wild here, too
add_action(
    'rewrite_rules_array',
    static function ($rules) {
        $newrules = array();
        // The true isn't important, it could be anything. The my-plugin is what
        // matters. Make sure to flush your permalinks!
        $newrules['my-plugin/?$'] = 'index.php?my-plugin=true';

        return $newrules + $rules;
    }
);

add_action(
    'template_include',
    static function ($template) {
        if (get_query_var('my-plugin')) {
            $template = get_template_directory() . '/searchform.php';
        }

        return $template;
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! :) I used option #2. I was able to get the content of the custom site displayed on the website, but the only problem is, that my custom CSS of the PHP/HTML file is overwritten. I guess the HTML head is overwritten by the admin template? Any solution for that? Or do I need to set the styling it inline?

Comment: Is it overwritten, or completely lost? My guess is the latter, and you're going to have to fix the URL for that, or just inline the CSS. To fix the URL, the recommended way is to enqueue your CSS and JS using the action [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/). That way is  admin-only but does include for every single admin page, even ones that aren't yours. If you want to enqueue only on specific admin pages, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41224/12496).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Chris! I was able to add my PHP-website and used inline CSS for now. I might refactor my PHP file with an implementation of a CSS file, but I am happy for now with the result.